# Tautological implication : what does $\alpha \to \beta$ mean?

Tags: logic

If $\alpha \to \beta$ is a tautology, it is clear that any assignment that satisfies $\alpha$ means that $\beta$ is always satisfied. But what about assignments that don't satisfy $\alpha$? Does this mean that $\beta$ will necessarily not be satisfied either?

Comment: I would assume that it is not possible to have a model satisfying $\alpha$ but not satisfying $\beta$ , which would give you a $T \rightarrow F$ assignment that invalidates, but I'm not 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ is (defined to be) logically equivalent to $\neg \alpha \vee \beta$, which is true exactly whenever either $\alpha$ is *false* or $\beta$ is *true* (or both).  When $\alpha$ is false the truth value of $\beta$ is completely irrelevant to the truth or falsity of the implication $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$: $\beta$ *could* be true, but it also *could* be false.

For example:

- "$2\text{ is odd} \rightarrow 2\text{ is even}$" is a true implication; and
- "$2\text{ is odd} \rightarrow 7\text{ is even}$" is also true implication.

In such cases we may say that the implication is [*vacuously* true](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aVacuous_Truth).

Answer (score 0):

You are "mixing" two different (but related) concepts : that of *tautology* and that of *tautological implication*.

We say that $\alpha$ is a *tautology* : $\vDash \alpha$, iff :

> $\alpha$ is *true* for all truth assigments.

We say that $\beta$ is a *tautological consequence* of $\alpha$, or that $\alpha$ *tautologically implies* $\beta$, : $\alpha \vDash \beta$, iff :

> all truth assignments satisfying $\alpha$ also satisfy $\beta$.

The (obvious) relation between the two notions is :

> > $\alpha \vDash \beta$ **iff** $\vDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$.

Thus, if $α→β$ is a tautology, we have that any truth assignment that satisfies $α$ must also satisfy $β$. But for an assignment that doesn't satisfy $α$, nothing follows regarding $β$.

According to the truth-functional properties of $\rightarrow$, if $v$ is an assignment such that $v(\alpha)=0$, then $v(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)=1$, irrespective of the value which $v$ assign to $\beta$.